# Size of an object at runtime

Tags: c#

How do you get the size(in bytes) of an object or data structure at runtime, I know there profiler tools that do this I am only interested in doing this at runtime.

Data Structure is `List<object>`

I am  trying to find out how much space the entire collection is taking and how much space an individual object is taking, not that there should, in theory, be a difference between the two.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/96747ab7-7d89-4846-9e83-46f71b8ccc66

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? Do you want to get the size of all the items in the collection? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I dont really see why you would need to know that as I would think the method to figure that out would involve the same mechanism

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [`sizeof` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf.aspx) only works for value and unmanaged types; [Marshal.SizeOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3ybkfb3.aspx) might give you what you need.